# Unusual definition of function measurability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I came across this definition "A function $f:\Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$ is measurable if it is $(\Sigma(\Omega_1), \Sigma(\Omega_2))$-measurable", where $\Omega_{1, 2}$ stands for Borel space and $\Sigma(\Omega_{1, 2})$ is a Borel $\sigma$-algebra. I do not understand the "$(\Sigma(\Omega_1), \Sigma(\Omega_2))$-measurable" part. What does it mean?? There is no additional elaboration on this definition as if it is some commonly known fact. The only definition of the function measurability I know is the one presented as follows: Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. Then function $f(x)$, $x\in X$, is measurable if for any $c\in R$ the set $\{x\in X|f(x)<c\}$ is measurable.

Comment: As written this definition is nonstandard. Rather, one takes the sigma algebra on the codomain to be the Borel one, and the sigma algebra on the domain one to be whatever is necessary for the purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Sigma_1$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega_1$, and similarly $\Sigma_2$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega_2$, the statement "$f\colon \Omega_1\to \Omega_2$ is measurable" means that for each $E\in\Sigma_2$, $f^{-1}(E)\in\Sigma_1$. This is analogous to the general definition of a continuous function $f\colon (X,\tau_1)\to (Y,\tau_2)$ of topological spaces, which says $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau_1$ for each $U\in\tau_2$.

In the context of functions taking values in $\mathbb R^n$, the $\sigma$-algebra we take on $\mathbb R^n$ is commonly the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, in which case measurability can equivalently be reformulated as asking
$$
f^{-1}(\prod_{i=1}^n(-\infty,a_i])\in\Sigma_1\quad\text{ for each $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb R^n$}.
$$

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thank you!! Now I understand.